# Who added the extra wards to Callandor?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

As of the end of *Towers of Midnight* do we know who added the extra wards to Callandor that were present when Jahar Narishma collected it for Rand in *The Path of Daggers*?

(The retrieval happened off screen, between chapters 14 and 21)

The dialog between Rand and Jahar is (written from Rand's point of view):

> Rand snatched the bundle before Narishma could proffer it. “Did anyone
> see you?” he demanded. “What took you so long? I expected you last night!”
>
> “It took a while to figure out what I had to do,” Narishma replied in
> a flat voice. “**You didn’t tell me everything. You nearly killed me.**”
>
> That was ridiculous. **Rand had told him everything he needed to know.
> He was sure of it.** There was no point to trusting the man as far as he
> had, only to have him die and ruin everything. Carefully he tucked the
> bundle beneath his cot. His hands trembled with the urge to strip the
> wrappings away, to make sure they held what Narishma had been sent
> for. The man would not have dared return if they did not. “Get
> yourself into a proper coat before you join the others,” he said. “And
> Narishma... ” Rand straightened, fixing the other man with a steady
> gaze. “You tell anyone about this, and I will kill you.”

*The Path of Daggers, Chapter 21 - "Answering the Summons"*

Comment: Lews Therin? :)

Comment: Has it been established (by anyone on Team Jordan) that there *were* extra wards? I mean, Rand is **crazy** after all. The passage you quoted doesn't really prove anything.

Comment: I am pretty sure it was RAFOed around the time of tPoD, but can't find the interview to back it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of this time, I believe there's no answer. The question has been asked of Brandon Sanderson and he neither RAFO'd it or answered it.

Check this [interview](http://theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=605#16) for details. It seems that this is a valid theory, but no clues at all so far about what the answer is, if any.